# Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I am very new to Objective.I am trying to make a simple application and after adding more view I get this error "Thread 1 Signal SIGABRT" and the app wont open in iOS Simulator. The error points to this line of code:

`return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`

I tried searching before but I didn't understand what the other answers were talking about.

NamesTableViewController.h is :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface NamesTableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end
```

NamesTableViewController.m is:

```
#import "NamesTableViewController.h"

@interface NamesTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *propertyList;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *letters;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSMutableArray *filteredNames;
@property (nonatomic, strong)UISearchController *searchController;


@end

    @implementation NamesTableViewController

    @synthesize propertyList,  letters, filteredNames, searchController;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

        [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        filteredNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]init];


        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"names" ofType:@"plist"];
        self.propertyList = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
        self.letters = [[self.propertyList allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        if (tableView.tag == 1){

            return self.letters.count;

        }else {
            return 1;
        }

        }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        if (tableView.tag == 1) {

            NSString *letter = self.letters[section];
            NSArray *keyValues = [self.propertyList[letter] allKeys];
            return keyValues.count;
        } else {


            return [filteredNames count];
        }
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...

        if (tableView.tag == 1){

            NSString *letter = self.letters[indexPath.section];;
            NSArray *keyValues = [[self.propertyList[letter] allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
            cell.textLabel.text = keyValues[indexPath.row];
        } else{
            cell.textLabel.text = filteredNames[indexPath.row];
        }
        return cell;
    }

    -(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return self.letters;
    }

    -(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        if (tableView.tag == 1) {
            return letters [section];
        } else {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    #pragma mark Search Display Delegate Methods

    -(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }



    -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString

    {

        [filteredNames removeAllObjects];
        if (searchString.length > 0) {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.searchBar.text];

            for (NSString *letter in letters) {
                NSArray *matches = [[self.propertyList[letter] allKeys]filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

                [filteredNames addObjectsFromArray:matches];

            }

        }

        return YES;
    }

    @end
```

**If you want more information just say it to me by answers and I will edit my question and then you will edit your answer**

Comment: Did you activate the exception breakpoints and saw where it crashes? (if you don't know how to, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode )

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: İ did it `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    NSString *key = names[section];

    NSArray *keyValues = keys[key];


    return [keyValues count];
}`

İt is working well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[keys allKeys]` returns an single-level array. Therefore there can be only one section.

**Edit:**

For better understanding and readability I replaced `names` with `letters` and `keys` with `propertyList`

• .h

The methods `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` retrieve the section letter and then the appropriate keys from the property list.

A dictionary as data source is not the best choice because there are many repetitive tasks to perform for example the sorting. Better create an nested array as data source in `viewDidLoad`

```
@interface NamesTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *propertyList;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *letters;

@end
```

• .m

```
@implementation NamesTableViewController

@synthesize propertyList, letters;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"names" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.propertyList = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.letters = [[self.propertyList allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.letters.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *letter = self.letters[section];
    NSArray *keyValues = [self.propertyList[letter] allKeys];
    return keyValues.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSString *letter = self.letters[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *keyValues = [[self.propertyList[letter] allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    cell.textLabel.text = keyValues[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.letters;
}

@end
```

Comment: How can I do it ? 
I am very new

Comment: What is the structure of the plist file? What are you going to accomplish?  Edit your question to give more information

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments. edit your question

Comment: Here 
`letters = [[keys allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];`
and here
`NSString *letter = letters[section];`
he complains

Comment: Sorry, it's `[propertyList allKeys]`. Renaming omission.

Comment: I edited the answer to add the missing `self` requirements and to correct an error `self.letters[indexPath.section];`

Comment: At the moment disclosure indicator don't show. Because of this I can't go to Detail View Controller. Can u help me again ?
P.S I updated the question code

Comment: That's beyond this question.

Comment: I know.All that you recommend worked. Now another problem

Comment: New question section to open?

Comment: I asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403921/why-disclosure-indicator-dont-show